# Do React functional components have any limitation in size?

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, react-functional-component

I'd like to ask this stupid question, because I've just faced with a very wierd issue with my react component. (I don't want to put any code here, trust me, the code is working).

Let's imagine, the return value (the TSX) of my component is about 328 lines long. Doesn't really matter, if I move the props into one line to decrease the length, the problem exists.

The error message is 'Failed to compile' and the details contains all of my hooks:

*Line 109:3:   React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render    react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

*Line 116:34:  React Hook "useCallback" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

*Line 128:57:  React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render     react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

*Line 130:3:   React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render    react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

....

If I comment out or remove some elements from the TSX, it compiles.
If I cut out a part of the TSX and put into a different function and call that function inside the returning TSX, it compiles.

Any ideas, what's happening behind the scenes?

(While I'm waiting to the answers, I start to split up this...)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you solve it? If so, how?

Comment: @VítorMartins unfortunately I haven't found the root cause of this behaviour, but I splitted up the code into smaller components. Anyways I planned to split it to increase the readability and reduce complexity.